# Print php output in pop window on submitting the form

Tags: php, html, forms, popup

I would like to print the output of PHP in a pop window after the submission of html form. Below is sample of my code.

```
<?php
 if(isset($_POST['button1']))
 {
    if("condition match")
    {
       echo "output1";
    }
    else
    {
       echo "output2";
    }
 } 
?>
<form class='n-form' action='#' method='post'>
 <div> 
  <button type='submit' name="button1" class='button'>Submit</button>
    <a href="../home.php" class="button">Cancel</a>
</div>
</form>
```

It should be able to print the echo output in the pop window based on the if condition.

Looking forward to hear.

Comment: try to change `if("condition match")` to  `if(!empty("condition match"))` and see if that makes a difference

Comment: It print, but I want it in pop window.

Answer (score 2):

There is no popout windows in php you have to do it in javascript

```
<?php
if(!empty($_POST))
{
    $text = (isset($_POST['button1'])) ? "output1" : "output2";
    echo '<script>alert("' . $text . '")</script>';
}
?>
```

Comment: This is correct. Using a builtin javascript alert, or a little nicer one like SweetAlert